# Is there a way to display without pattern recognition?

Tags: augmented-reality

With Augmented Reality, is there any way to display a 3d model or anything without the need for pattern recognition? There is a service that allows you to try on rings using augmented reality but it required pattern recognition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically there is a pattern, but it's an invisible pattern...

When you do 3D tracking or SLAM, you're not tracking a printed pattern, but a map made of the object or environment.  However, hands are hard. It works better with static objects like buildings.

Here's some more info about it:

http://dev.metaio.com/toolbox/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you're augmenting. If for example, you have a phone with accelerometers etc, and for example you want to show the cheapest price of a pint of cider above a nightclub's door, you don't need pattern recognition. However, if you want to process what the camera is seeing (e.g. your ring example) and respond to that, then you do need pattern recognition. You also need pattern recognition if you're some how responding to audio - or things like that - not that I can think of how or why you'd want to do that.